# Is $0.1010010001000010000010000001 \ldots$ transcendental?

Tags: transcendental-numbers, decimal-expansion

Does anyone know if this number is algebraic or transcendental, and why?

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {10}^{ - n(n + 1)/2}  = 0.1010010001000010000010000001 \ldots $$

Comment: Well, it's *almost* a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number), but the obvious good approximations are not that good ...

Comment: I can't answer the question but do remember that this or similar questions were answered in the book "Aufgaben und Lehrsaetze aus der Analysis" by Polya and Szego. I no longer have this book but it is a serious place to look for the solution to this question.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Consider the first three terms of the sum: $0.1 + 0.001 + 0.000001$ The big chains of zeroes for smaller terms are "hidden" by the larger terms to the left :)

Comment: IIRC this is a challenge problem in *Tools of the Trade* by Paul Sally. I remember finding some reference a few years ago (after Sally assigned it to me among a list of problems) to this being open.

Comment: Yes it must be transcendental since it is the root of a geometric sequence which is not a polynomial. Or wait... is that a valid argument?

Comment: Wait, I was being stupid, it's not a geometric sequence even.

Comment: Transcendal it is.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The number $0.1010010001000010000010000001\ldots$ is transcendental.

Consider following three Jacobi [theta series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function) defined by
$$\begin{align}
\theta_2(q) 
&= 2q^{1/4}\sum_{n\ge 0} q^{n(n+1)} = 2q^{1/4}\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{4n})(1 + q^{2n})\\
\theta_3(q)
&= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n})(1+ q^{2n-1})^2\\
\theta_4(q)
&= \theta_3(-q) =
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} (-1)^n q^{n^2} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n})(1- q^{2n-1})^2\\
\end{align}
$$
and for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, $k \in \{ 2, 3, 4 \}$, use 
$\displaystyle D^m\theta_k(q)$ as a shorthand for 
$\displaystyle \left( q\frac{d}{dq} \right)^m \theta_k(q)$.

Based on Corollary 52 of a survey article [Elliptic functions and Transcendence](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~miw/articles/pdf/SurveyTrdceEllipt2006.pdf) by M. Waldschmidt in 2006,

> Let $i, j$ and $k \in \{ 2,3,4 \}$ with $i \ne j$. Let $q \in \mathbb{C}$
>   satisfy $0 < |q| < 1$. Then each of the two fields
>   $$
> \mathbb{Q}( q, \theta_i(q), \theta_j(q), D\theta_k(q))
> \quad\text{ and }\quad
> \mathbb{Q}( q, \theta_k(q), D\theta_k(q), D^2\theta_k(q))
> $$
>   has transcendence degree $\ge 3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

We know for any non-zero algebraic $q$ with $|q| < 1$, the three $\theta_k(q)$, in particular $\theta_2(q)$ is transcendental. Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n(n+1)/2} = \frac{\sqrt[8]{10}}{2} \theta_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right) - 1$$

and using the fact $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\frac{\sqrt[8]{10}}{2}$ are both algebraic, we find the number at hand is transcendental.

Comment: "Take a prime that's not a prime" What's a prime that isn't a prime? 1? -1?

Comment: @Joao, 1 and -1 are units and not primes. There is a famous composite number which has been known as "************ prime".

Comment: @achillehui Are you giving the solution to "************ prime" yet :)?

Comment: @Ovi  it is [57](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_%28number%29).

Comment: Grothendieck prime ($57$) needs [$42$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) to make it $99$.