# Rationality or irrationality of $\log$ function

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Can this be proved that $\log(n)$ is irrational for every $n=1,2,3,\dots$ ?

I find that question in my mind in searching for if $\log(x)$ is irrational for every rational number $x\gt0$.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $e$ is transcendental

Comment: [Related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360042/prove-logx-is-transcendental)

Answer (score 5):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\neq 1$. Suppose that there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\log(n)=\frac{a}{b}$. Then we have that $n=e^{a/b}$ is a trancendental number since $e$ is a trancendental number and $\frac{a}{b}$ is rational. This is a contradiction. Therefore, $\log(n)$ is irrational for every $n=2,3,4,....$

Comment: Excellent! You can in fact take $n\in\mathbb Q$ without changing anything to completly answer OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem (mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/809913/68107)) that for any nonzero $\alpha$, at least one of $\alpha$ and $e^{\alpha}$ is transcendental.

In this case, take $\alpha = \log x$, where $x$ is rational.
Then either $\log x$ is transcendental, or $x$ is.
But $x$ is rational, hence algebraic. So $\log x$ is transcendental, and in particular it is irrational.