# Generalized case for identifying transcendental numbers

Tags: number-theory

For any strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $ a_1...a_n $, is the expression given below transcendental? Stack Exchange gives a specific case [Is $0.1010010001000010000010000001 \ldots$ transcendental?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778218/is-0-1010010001000010000010000001-ldots-transcendental?noredirect=1&lq=1) , with $ a_n=n$, as transcendent, but people I've asked don't think that can be generalized to all cases, likewise with using Liouville's inequality.

$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} 10^{-a_i} $

Answer (score 0):

Modern mathematics knows very little about transcendental numbers. The closest thing we have to a general case is $a^b$ where $a$ is algebraic but not $0$ or $1$, and $b$ is irrational algebraic (by the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem)), in particular: $2^{\sqrt{2}}$, the [Gelfond-Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant#:%7E:text=The%20Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider%20constant%20or,by%20Rodion%20Kuzmin%20in%201930.) (or Hilbert number).